# Facebook scam error for web app

Tags: facebook, git, heroku

I am testing an integration of Facebook with external web app under facebook canvas.

### I got down to just having a simple HTML page, but still getting the SCAM error.

"Stop!

This is a browser feature intended for developers. If someone told you to copy-paste something here to enable a Facebook feature or "hack" someone's account, it is a scam and will give them access to your Facebook account.

### For more information, see https://www.facebook.com/selfxss." in Chrome and similar message in Firefox.

### The page is not displaying. I only can see "Cannot POST/fb_source=bookmark&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=3_0"

My app is hosted on heroky and currently have just "HELLO APP NEW" text, no more.
GITHUB: git@heroku.com:better-you-v0-1.git
HEROKU: https://better-you-v0-1.herokuapp.com/#

What can be a reason for that?

Comment: We always show it. And it have nothing to with your app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a warning shown by Facebook to its users to prevent people tricking them into performing self-XSS attacks on themselves - it's not related to whatever problem you're having with your app

Comment: Thank you. 
Yes, the issue was in my server.js file

Comment: What I'm reading is that this is normal, and also @AlexeyOmelchenko it would be helpful to specify what the issue was in your server.js file and if it made this message go away.

Comment: @OliverWilliams No, this message will always be there regardless of what you do. It's not an error but just a message from Facebook to its users and has nothing to do with the rest of the code you have written.